# Prove: $g_{0}\circ f_{0}$ and $g_{1}\circ f_{1}$ are homotopic maps $X\to Z$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces. Suppose that $f_{0}$ and $f_{1}$ are homotopic maps $X\to Y$ and that $g_{0}$ and $g_{1}$ are homotopic maps $Y\to Z$. Then $g_{0}\circ f_{0}$ and $g_{1}\circ f_{1}$ are homotopic maps $X\to Z$.

Consider:
break the proof into two steps:

a) $g_{0}\circ f_{0}\simeq g_{0}\circ f_{1}$

b) $g_{0}\circ f_{1}\simeq g_{1}\circ f_{1}$

How can I prove two parts of them?

Comment: What have you tried/attempted?

Comment: The part a),I think I may make it by :
  $F:X\times I\to Y$ be a homotopy from $f_{0}$ to $f_{1}$. Let $G=g_{0}\circ F:X\times I\to Z$. Then $G$ is a homotopy from $g_{0}\circ f_{0}$ to $g_{0}\circ f_{1}$.
  Actually, I don't understand how to prove the part b). Thank you.